# Dynamically add a full svg shape (with pure Javascript)

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to draw a square by using path in SVG created with JS. But the browsers do not accept this:

Javascript:

```
var svg = document.createElement('svg');
svg.width = "200";
svg.height = "200";
document.body.appendChild(svg);

var path = document.createElement('path');
path.setAttribute('d','M100,0 L200,100 100,200 0,100Z');
path.setAttribute('fill','red');
svg.appendChild(path);
```

HTML (output):

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <path d="M100,0 L200,100 100,200 0,100Z" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

createElement can only be used to create html elements. To create SVG elements you must use createElementNS and supply the SVG namespace as the first argument.

Also document.body.appendChild('svg'); is presumably a typo as you want to add the svg element and not a string containing the text 'svg'

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
svg.setAttribute('width','200');
svg.setAttribute('height','200');
document.body.appendChild(svg);

var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
path.setAttribute('d','M100,0 L200,100 100,200 0,100Z');
path.setAttribute('fill','red');
svg.appendChild(path);
```

Comment: Yup. I did not know where to put setAttribureNS or createElementNS. That is why I asked the question as simple as possible to get quick a simple and a complete answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `createElementNS` instead of `createElement`.